# Method not performing the right logic

Tags: android

Please refer the image below:

[image: android studio screenshot]

In the method `isSelectableInMultiChoiceMode`, one can notice that the debugger has reached **line 160**, when it should return from **line 157**. The debugger got inside the `if` condition on **line 155** but didn't go inside the next(nested) `if` condition.

From the **'Variables'** section below, we can see that `position` is **0**, `mListItems` has **9** items and the first item is `instance of` `ResultsAdapter.SectionHeaderItem`.

Then what could be the reason for debugger returning from **line 160**?

For anyone curious, I am using [this](https://github.com/dvdciri/MultiChoiceRecyclerView/) library. (Which I don't think should matter)

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Line 156 have to be false

Comment: @An-droid, thanks but the condition in line 156 is true, the first item of mListItems is instance of ResultsAdapter.SectionHeaderItem. (Can be seen from the debugger output below).

Comment: @Henry, thanks for the advice but I wanted to show the debugger output and the 'popup' which shows that the class 'SectionHeaderItem' on line 156 is actually 'ResultsAdapter.SectionHeaderItem'. Otherwise people would have asked questions about me probably missing something here or there. So a picture is worth a thousand words. :)

Comment: Did you edit the relevant lines recently? (and are you sure that the newest version is running on your device?) How about InstantRun? In some AndroidStudio versions there have been bugs because InstantRun was enabled. If nothing else helps: uninstall app, exit Android Studio,  restart development machine, restart Android Studio - and good luck!

Comment: @0X0nosugar, thanks.. I did as you said but still the same issue. (And I have disabled Instant Run).

Comment: It looks like the code in the editor is not the code which is executed. What happens if you copy-paste this class into a new class, rename all the necessary parts and use the new class?